# How to pass multi line string as an argument in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am calling a simple python script to which im passing variables. One of the variable is a multi line string. This works fine when calling the python script from power shell, but when im calling the script from cmd, its not taking the full string as the argument.

```
python myscript.py "Argument1" "Argument2" "MultiString"
```

Multiline string is coming directly as a field from an application.

```
Type:           Associate
Last Name:      Lastname
First Name:     Firstname
Business Unit Group:    Business Unit Group
Dept Code:      Dept Code
Department Name:    Department Name
Locations:      Locations
Manager:        Manager
Title:          Title
Start Date:     Start Date
Term Date:      Term Date

================================================================
If you have any information regarding the termination of this Associate, please contact the hiring Manager.
```

Comment: ty for the edit @tdelaney

Comment: I assume this is the windows command line? If so, note that in the question. For a bash like unix shell, just the quotes with the multiline string should work but I don't have Windows up to test CMD. I don't understand what you mean by getting the data from an application. Are you pasting this multiline string into the command prompt?

Comment: I am calling the py script from an application and the multiline string is stored in a filed in a form from that application. That application is pasting the multi line string automatically in the command prompt when i run the script from that application.

Comment: The application pastes the string in a command prompt? Usually applications call functions to execute commands. For instance, a python program may call `subprocess.run(...)`. That it would call an api to run a command prompt and then another to paste the data into that prompt seems like a difficult way to make a simple call.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Argparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('first_string', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('second_string', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.first_string)
print(args.secons_string)
```

test it:

```
python myscript.py "first string..." "second string..."
```